# (three.js) - Any way to dynamically create a texture and apply to a Mesh object?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to figure out how i could possibly create a texture (at run-time) so that I can load and apply that to a material.

**Example scenario:**

When user types "hello world", a simple 128px x 128px white image (bitmap) is created in memory with a black text "Hello world" in the middle. Then a Box geometry get this texture mapping applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a canvas as a texture and add the text to the canvas.
[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450716/animating-canvas-billboard-in-three-js) is a stack question that uses a canvas as a texture that might help you.